# Annotate NSArray<NSNumber *> * in Objective-C so that it is bridged to Array<Int>

Tags: objective-c, swift, types, bridging

Is there a way to annotate an `NSArray` of `NSNumber`:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray<NSNumber *> *myProperty
```

in Objective-C, so that it will be imported in Swift as

`var myProperty: [Int]` instead of `var myProperty: [NSNumber]`?

I know of `NS_SWIFT_NAME`, but that does not allow changing the *type*.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly? Do you need an `Int` array or `NSNumber` array in swift? Or maybe an `Int` array in Objective c?

Comment: An `Int` array in Swift from an `NSArray<NSNumber *> *` in Objective-C.

Comment: After asking the question I researched a little more. I don't think it's possible. If you look at the `allowedTouchTypes` property of `UIGestureRecognizer`. That one is also an `NSArray<NSNumber *> *` return type, and is imported in Swift as `[NSNumber]`.

Comment: @Trenskow you can get any element from your number array `[NSNumber]` and access its `intValue` property which will return an `Int`. You can also map all elements `numbers.map{$0.intValue}` will return an array of Int `[Int]`

Comment: @Trenskow If you are working with NSArray you would need to cast from `Any` to `NSNumber` `numbers.flatMap{($0 as? NSNumber)?.intValue}`. But you should  work with Swift native Array type

Comment: Yes. I'm designing an API, and I would like this to be automatically imported as this in Swift, but I know now, that it is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the static type when importing a symbol from Objective-C.

But you can assign a Swift `Int` array without any type cast (assuming `foo` is an instance of the ObjC class). However the type doesn't change.

```
foo.myProperty = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(type(of: foo.myProperty)) // Optional<Array<NSNumber>>
```

On the other hand to get a distinct `[Int]` type you have to cast the type

```
let mySwiftProperty = foo.myProperty as! [Int]
print(type(of: mySwiftProperty)) // Array<Int>
```

Comment: I accept this as the correct answer. After the initial question I did some research, and even UIKit does this, so I guess it's not possible. I just wanted not to make it my users responsibility to cast it to the correct type. Thanks!